# What interaction is possible during visible lifetime of an Android activity?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

From [Android Activities API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks):

> The visible lifetime of an activity happens between the call to
>   onStart() and the call to onStop(). During this time, the user can see
>   the activity on-screen and interact with it.

I may be over analyzing, but I am confused by what is meant by '... and interact with it.'.

I thought during the foreground lifetime is when the activity has focus and that is the only time interaction is possible.

Is there some sort of user interaction possible between the calls to `onStart()` and `onResume()`, and also `onPause()` and `onStop()`?

I have little Android experience, just reading the docs to get an overview.

Comment: That is probably just an old and poorly-written passage from the documentation. The activity is at least partially visible betwen `onStart()` and `onResume()` (and between `onPause()` and `onStop()`), but some other activity is deemed to be in the foreground from an input standpoint, so key and touch events should go to that other activity. I do not know what else, besides key and touch events, they might have been considering with respect to "interact with it".

Answer (score 0):

Is there some sort of user interaction possible between the calls to onStart() and onResume(), and also onPause() and onStop()?

There is tiny amount of time between onStart and onResume (as well as between onPause and onStop) so it is not the case to perform user interactions. However you should understand and use the difference between these calls, for example use onPause call when your activity is overlapped by other activity or dialog, but still stays partly visible. In this case onStop is not being called. You might want to use onRestart method if you want something to be called only when activity is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

When the activity A is in the foreground its between onResume & onPause.

When the activity A is in the background, with a second foreground activity B that is perhaps transparent, then its possible for the background activity A to be between onPause -> onStop. Its not stopped because the user can still see things happening there.

I'm do not know what kind of direct interactions can happen, as most of the touch events are handled in B. Perhaps you could perform indirect interactions with it. For example a button click on Activity B keeps changing the background color of Activity A when you setResults(). But I suppose this is kind of overstretching it.